# arrows with same length between spaces

Tags: amsmath, arrows

I have a problem regarding code in latex. The problem is that the length of the arrows are different depending on the length of the labeling of the maps. e.g. the map `{f_{x_0}}` has an arrow which is longer than the map `{g_*}`. Is there a way to fix this? And is there a way to make the arrow a little longer, they are very short.

```
\begin{equation*}
\pi_1(X,x_0) \xrightarrow{f_{x_0}}  \pi_1(Y,y_0) \xrightarrow{g_*} \pi_1(X,x_1) \xrightarrow{f_{x_1}} \pi_1(Y,y_1)
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Please always show a complete document or at least mention the packages you are using. This was tagged tex-core but `\xrightarrow` is not defined by TeX or even latex by default.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{mathtools} 
\begin{document}  


\begin{equation*}
\pi_1(X,x_0) \xrightarrow{\mathmakebox[1.5cm]{f_{x_0}}}
\pi_1(Y,y_0) \xrightarrow{\mathmakebox[1.5cm]{g_*}}
\pi_1(X,x_1) \xrightarrow{\mathmakebox[1.5cm]{f_{x_1}}} 
\pi_1(Y,y_1)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```